# Playframework 2.2.1 Scala - Form bindFromRequest error

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to register a tuple to a DB and upload the image to Amazon S3.

I divided the code to two parts : 1) Working Code and 2) Non Working Code.

Working code means It works as expected. The image file is uploaded sucessfully to S3.

Non working code is always folding to index_error page which I'm trying to solve but I can't figure out where I'm missing.

Thank you for help!

Working Code

```
def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.upload_test_index("File Upload In Play"))
}

def uploadFile = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
  request.body.file("fileUpload").map { video =>

  val newFile = File.createTempFile("temp-uploaded-", video.filename)
  video.ref.moveTo(newFile, true)

  new S3Sender(newFile, video.filename).send

}.getOrElse {
  Redirect(routes.Application.index)
}
Ok("File has been uploaded")
```

}

Non Working Code - Controller

```
val anuncioForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "label" -> nonEmptyText,
    "imgName" -> text
  )
)


def createAnuncio = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
  anuncioForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.index_error(formWithErrors)),
    {
      case (label, imgName) =>
        request.body.file("imgName").map { imgName =>
        val newFile = File.createTempFile("temp-uploaded-", imgName.filename)
        val fileName = imgName.filename
        imgName.ref.moveTo(newFile, true)
        new S3Sender(newFile, fileName).send
        Anuncio.create(label, fileName)
      }

      println("criou")
      Redirect(routes.Application.anuncios)
    }
  )
}

  def anuncios = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(Anuncio.all(), anuncioForm))
  }

  def newAnuncio = Action {
    Ok(views.html.create(anuncioForm))
  }
```

Non Working Code - Template

```
@(anuncioForm: Form[(String, String)])

@import helper._

@main("Criar um novo anuncio") {

@form(action = routes.Application.createAnuncio, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
    @inputText(anuncioForm("label"))
    @*<input type="file" name="imgName">*@
    @inputFile(anuncioForm("imgName"))

    <input type="submit" value="Create">
}
}
```

Edited

I used the code below to know the error message.

```
formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.index_error(formWithErrors.errorsAsJson))
```

Surprisingly I got the message below. I can't figure out why this message?!

```
{"imgName":["This field is required"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have the file contents as a part of the form itself? You declare the imgName as a text in the form in your controller, but you use it as a input type="file" in your view, which I would imagine is contradictory.

A few things you could take a look at:

- [how to handle fileupload into a table in play framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424782/how-to-handle-fileupload-into-a-table-in-play-framework) which talks about separating the file from the form as well as an (untested?) single submit for both a form and a file, and possible some other clues
- [How to include a picture type in a form in Play!2 in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430749/how-to-include-a-picture-type-in-a-form-in-play2-in-scala) which is doing something similar to what you are doing
- http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/ScalaFileUpload